# wordpress website database size increasing daily

Tags: database, wordpress

my website database size increased daily when I clear used CSS with the help of wp rocket then it comes to normal but after few hours it again reaches to limit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue a few months back with wp-rocket on my Website.
After adjust the setting in cache-lifespan in wp-rocket settings to 10 hours, it worked. As wp-rocket caches not globaly, but each page/post, the cache increases fast when having alot of content.